# Linq query with multiple count

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I am trying to query this table using LINQ:

[image]

Here's what I want to do:

[image]

Here's my LINQ query:

```
var query = from a in table 
            where a.Country.Equals("USA")
            group a by a.Product_brand into grp
            select new
            {
              Product_brand = grp.key.Product_brand,
              Country = grp.Key.Country,
              Black = grp.Count(a => a.Black=="Yes"),
              White = grp.Count(a => a.White=="Yes"),
              Red = grp.Count(a=> a.Red=="Yes"),
              Green = grp.Count(a=> a.Green=="Yes")
            }
```

I don't know what's wrong with my query, I keep getting this message:

[image]

Alternative Solution:

Sql query:

```
SELECT [Product brand], Country,
sum(case when [Black] = 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end) as Black,
sum(case when [White] = 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end) as White,
sum(case when [Red] = 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end) as Red,
sum(case when [Green] = 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end) as Green,
FROM            dbo.Table

group by [Product brand], Country
```

Comment: This doesn't seem some problem in linq, maybe it's in your connection.

Comment: Is your server down or unreachable? Your query looks fine: as long as the size of your table is not in the billions of rows, you should get your results reasonably quickly.

Comment: the server is definitely not down, and I just tested the connection It's working

Comment: How many rows are in your table?

Comment: Do you still get the issue if you remove the groupbys?

Comment: @Zack09, looks like something to do with DB connection strings

Comment: @DaveBish I tested some other queries they're working just fine,

Comment: Maybe SQL Server is just timing out, try and change the timeout property of your sql instance

Comment: Run SQL profiler to see if your db gets hit. If it does, see what SQL is being generated/executed and see if it's a LINQ issue or SQL issue.

Comment: I'm with Xikinho90. Can we see the timeout property of your connectionstring?

Comment: I found a way around my problem, I used a View instead. Then I used a simple Linq Query to display the results. Thanks Everyone

Comment: What a shame - running away, instead of understanding and solving the problem :)

Comment: How were you getting the values from the **anonymous type**?

Comment: @christiandev by converting it to list (query.ToList()) and displaying it in a DataGridView

Answer (score 6):

You have to group by two fields if you want it to work
something like:

```
var query = from a in table 
        where a.Country.Equals("USA")
        group a by new {a.Product_brand, a.Country} into grp
        select new
        {
          Product_brand = grp.key.Product_brand,
          Country = grp.Key.Country,
          Black = grp.Count(a => a.Black=="Yes"),
          White = grp.Count(a => a.White=="Yes"),
          Red = grp.Count(a=> a.Red=="Yes"),
          Green = grp.Count(a=> a.Green=="Yes")
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In VB.Net code is like that

```
Dim query=(from a in table
where a.Country = "USA"
group a by a.Product_brand,a.country into grp = group _
select new with
{
     .Product_brand=Product_brand,
     .country=country,
     .Black = grp.Count(Function(a) a.Black="Yes"),
     .White = grp.Count(Function(a) a.White="Yes"),
     .Red = grp.Count(Function(a) a.Red="Yes"),
     .Green = grp.Count(Function(a) a.Green="Yes")
})
```